# Running a 32bit Installer with a 64bit operating system (windows)

Tags: windows, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

I have an executable (setup.exe) that is being created using inno studio. for the executable to run I have to install a certain dll, which is libusb0.dll. If the system is a 64 bit I have the 64 bit dll being installed inside the system32 folder, also if the application is a 32 bit, it is installed in the syswow64 folder. Now if the system is a 32 bit I have the directory set to install the 32 bit dll in the system32 folder accordingly .

Although there seems to be another case, for example if the system is 64 bit, but the installer is 32bit, will the installer be able to identify that the system is a 64 bit and install it in the correct directory, which would be the syswow64 folder to install the 32bit dlls, or will it still try and install the 32 bit dll into the system32 folder which would be incorrect since its for 64bit dlls on a 64 bit system? In which case the setup will fail to find the correct dll?

I hope this makes sense, it is a little confusing for me, but would be nice to get someone's opinion on it.

The way I have it implemented in inno studio, is that I'm using Check: Is64BitInstallMode so that it checks the system before placing the respective dlls in the system folders.

Comment: The bitness of the installer is irrelevant, the bitness of the program being installed is. The library bitness must match the program bitness, so no choosing here either. The installer always knows what bitness it is installing, so not sure where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that this really wouldn't be an issue, thanks for the response